# PowerShell: How do I convert an array object to a string in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I convert an array object to string?

I tried:

```sh
$a = "This", "Is", "a", "cat"
[system.String]::Join(" ", $a)
```

<strike>with no luck</strike>. What are different possibilities in PowerShell?

Comment: See my answer but your code works just fine, too. Why do you say "with no luck"?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it does seem to work, I think I messed up something when I tested this.

Answer (score 356, accepted):

```sh
$a = 'This', 'Is', 'a', 'cat'
```

Using double quotes (and optionally use the separator `$ofs`)

```sh
# This Is a cat
"$a"

# This-Is-a-cat
$ofs = '-' # after this all casts work this way until $ofs changes!
"$a"
```

Using operator join

```sh
# This-Is-a-cat
$a -join '-'

# ThisIsacat
-join $a
```

Using conversion to `[string]`

```sh
# This Is a cat
[string]$a

# This-Is-a-cat
$ofs = '-'
[string]$a
```

Comment: For the un-initiated (like me) `$ofs` is documented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/5353/automatic-variables/19045/ofs)

Comment: Stackoverflow Documentation has been shut down so Liam's link is dead.  Here's another explanation of $OFS, the Output Field Separator: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/07/15/psmdtagfaq-what-is-ofs/

Comment: Why is it called OFS ? It's a weird name considering it's been called IFS on standard shell for decades and decades.

Comment: @JohanBoulé : Because using the first character of the Input Field Separator as the Output Field Separator is a nasty hack - and doesn't allow separating fields with multi-character strings.  (Awk for example has FS and OFS variables).

Comment: @martin bonner : thanks, it makes sense now. I don't know how I messed this up.

Comment: Official documentation is here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/blob/staging/reference/6/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_Preference_Variables.md#ofs

Comment: Seems you can't edit comments after a certain time. Here's a couple of working links: [learn.microsoft.com PowerShell 7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.1#ofs) [GitHub PowerShell 7.1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/blob/4295a917fcb0140aa96426cc2ef8f861771d36cf/reference/7.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_Preference_Variables.md#ofs)

Comment: "$OFS is a special variable that contains the string to be used as the Ouptut Field Sperator. **This string is used when an array is converted to a string. By default, this is ” ” but you can change it.**"

Answer (score 49):

I found that piping the array to the [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-6) cmdlet works well too.

For example:

```
PS C:\> $a  | out-string

This
Is
a
cat
```

It depends on your end goal as to which method is the best to use.

Comment: FYI: just doing `$a` would have the same effect as `$a | out-string`

Comment: @JohnLBevan Not always.  `($a | out-string).getType()` = String.  `$a.getType()` = Object[].  If you're using $a as an argument to a method expecting a string (such as `invoke-expression` for example), then `$a | out-string` has a clear advantage.

Comment: Tried this - note that Out-String can truncate long lines based on the characteristics of the host program, so you may experience long variables been wrapped to another line - see the Width parameter.

Answer (score 24):

```
1> $a = "This", "Is", "a", "cat"

2> [system.String]::Join(" ", $a)
```

Line two performs the operation and outputs to host, but does not modify $a:

```
3> $a = [system.String]::Join(" ", $a)

4> $a

This Is a cat

5> $a.Count

1
```

Answer (score 13):

From a pipe

```r
# This Is a cat
'This', 'Is', 'a', 'cat' | & {"$input"}

# This-Is-a-cat
'This', 'Is', 'a', 'cat' | & {$ofs='-';"$input"}
```

Write-Host

```r
# This Is a cat
Write-Host 'This', 'Is', 'a', 'cat'

# This-Is-a-cat
Write-Host -Separator '-' 'This', 'Is', 'a', 'cat'
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/cbbc1a4cd/windows.ps1#L78-L84)

Comment: This is amazing trick. The Example does not work anymore, and even though this answer is 5 years old, I try to explain what I learned today. The `$ofs` is `Output Field Separator` variable which is used when an array is converted into string for output. Here it is set in the script block returning string value of the input (array from the pipe) which gets executed by the command `&`. I didn't know about `$ofs` before, as well as `&` accepting a script block as argument

Comment: `$input` variable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#input

Answer (score 4):

You could specify type like this:

```
[string[]] $a = "This", "Is", "a", "cat"
```

Checking the type:

```
$a.GetType()
```

Confirms:

```
    IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
    -------- -------- ----                                     --------
    True     True     String[]                                 System.Array
```

Outputting $a:

```
PS C:\> $a 
This 
Is 
a 
cat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = "This", "Is", "a", "cat"

foreach ( $word in $a ) { $sent = "$sent $word" }
$sent = $sent.Substring(1)

Write-Host $sent
```