# Join an array with newline in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, join

I have an array of names that I'm trying to join using a new line character.  I have the following code

```
$body = $invalid_hosts -join "`r`n"
$body = "The following files in $Path were found to be invalid and renamed `n`n" + $body
```

Finally, I send the contents via email.

```
$From = "myaddress@domain.com"
$To = "myaddress@domain.com
$subject = "Invalid language files"

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "smtp.domain.com" -From $From -To $To -Subject $subject -Body $body
```

When I receive the message, the line `The following files in <filepath> were found to be invalid and renamed` has the expected double space, but the contents of $invalid_hosts are all on one line. I've also tried doing

```
$body = $invalid_hosts -join "`n"
```

and

```
$body = [string]::join("`n", $invalid_hosts)
```

Neither way is working. What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: This is not a duplicate as this problem specifically occurs in body of email when using Send-MailMessage in plain text mode.

Comment: Please notice that since Outlook 2003 double `\n` are removed by default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/line-breaks-are-removed-in-posts-made-in-plain-text

Answer (score 35):

Pipe the array to the `Out-String` cmdlet to convert them from a collection of string objects to a single string:

```
PS> $body = $invalid_hosts -join "`r`n" | Out-String
```

Comment: @Robbert, you must have made a mistake. Try hard-coding $body and see what happens: `$body = "This\`nIs\`nA\`nTest"`

Comment: It did the same thing I described above.  In the end, I decided the issue may have been the formatting done by Outlook and changed the output to an HTML message. Instead of using a newline, I joined the array using `<br/>`.

Comment: Isn't `join "\`r\`n"` redundant to `| Out-String`?  Why use both in the same command?

Comment: I had the same problem as @Robbert - it only worked for me when sending email as HTML with "<br/>" as separator when joining string array.

Comment: NB Out-String can truncate long lines based on the characteristics of the host program, so you may experience long variables been wrapped to another line - see the Width parameter.

Answer (score 20):

It is sufficient just pipe to Out-String (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21322311/52277)

```
 $result = 'This', 'Is', 'a', 'cat'
 $strResult = $result  | Out-String
 Write-Host $strResult
This
Is
a
cat
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm unsure about how to answer everything else, but for guaranteed newlines in Powershell, use:
[Environment]::NewLine in place of your "`n"

Comment: This worked for me, using \`r\`n simply output \`r\`n

Answer (score 7):

Had to solve this today; thought I'd share my answer since the question and other answers helped me find the solution.  Instead of

```
$body = $invalid_hosts -join "`r`n"
$body = "The following files in $Path were found to be invalid and renamed `n`n" + $body
```

use

```
$MessageStr = "The following files in " + $Path + " were found to be invalid and renamed"
$BodyArray = $MessageStr + $Invalid_hosts
$Body = $BodyArray -join "`r`n"
```

Answer (score 3):

I went about it differently and just replaced the newline

```
$result -replace("`r`n"," ")
```

Comment: This would do the opposite, replacing new line characters with a space.

Answer (score 2):

I am certainly no expert in PowerShell, but I found a much easier way to do it.  Simply pipe to `Write-Host` like this:

```
$array = 'This', 'Is', 'a', 'cat'
$array | Write-Host

Output:
This
Is
a
cat
```

This is a slightly different use case than the OP question.  It does not join the array with newlines, but it does give newlines when writing the output.