# How to join the output of object array to a string in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a variable with the following output in PowerShell. How do I join the result to a string?

### For example

$s

Output:

### Name

abc
def
ghi

I want the output to be in a single string as below:

### Name

abc, def, ghi

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell: how to convert array object to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723584/powershell-how-to-convert-array-object-to-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join $s using a comma. Try this:

```
$s -join ','
```

Edit, I noticed you want a space after the comma, so:

```
$s -join ', '
```

Output is this:

```
abc, def, ghi
```

Edit, if you want to save the result in $s do the following:

```
$s = $s -join ', '
```

New Edit. I didn't see your code, now it's clearer. Try the following:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.RMO") | Out-Null 
$repsvr = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ReplicationServer" "localhost" 

$s = ($repsvr | select -expand RegisteredSubscribers | select Name) -join ', '
```