# How to read an element in XML file in PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INITIAL>
    <FB1>a</FB1>
    <FB2>b</FB2>
    <FB3>c</FB3>
    <FB4>d</FB4>
    <FB5>e</FB5>
    <FB6>f</FB6>
    <FB7>g</FB7>
    <FB8>h</FB8>
    <FB9>i</FB9>

</INITIAL>
```

I just want to read element a to iand convert it to string, be like this :

```
abcdefghi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this XML:

```
<INITIAL>
    <FB1>fr</FB1>
    <FB2>fs</FB2>
    <FB3>...</FB3>
</INITIAL>
```

fetching the `InnerText` of the container element will be enough:

```
Write-Host $xml.DocumentElement.InnerText
```

This would print `frfs...`.

If in your actual XML the container isn't the top-most element, substitute `DocumentElement` with `.SelectSingleNode('some/xpath')`.

Answer (score 0):

You first create an System.Xml.XmlDocument out of it. Here is an example:

```
$theXml = [xml](gc $xmlPath)
$theXml.GetType().fullname
```

Once you have it, you can play-around the way you want! - In your example, you need concatenation of values of child elements. You would find lot of example online how to concatenate string values from an Array - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723584/how-do-i-convert-an-array-object-to-a-string-in-powershell)

```
$theXml.INITIAL.GetEnumerator() # this gives you enumeration of values in children to the 'INITIAL' element.
```

I Hope this helps.

Edit: And yeah, your xml was broken - I assume it added closing tags like `</FB1>` for all.

Comment: I tried this :
$XML = [xml](gc "C:\Users\XML.xml")
$XML.GetType().FullName

It error : Cannot convert value System.Object[] to type System.Xml.XmlDocument. This document already has a DocumentElement node

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XPath expression to get the nodes you want and then use the `-join` operator to join the strings together.

The XPath expression `/INITIAL/*` means every element directly inside the `INITIAL` element at top level. Taking care to select the data you actually want will help you if someone later decides to extend the data format somehow.

```
PS> $Data = New-Object Xml
PS> $Data.Load((Resolve-Path file.xml))

PS> $Data.SelectNodes("/INITIAL/*")."#text" -join ""
frfsftfufvfwfhgKfg
```

Tested with Windows PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Using SelectNodes is error : Exception calling "SelectNodes" with "1" argument(s): "Expression must evaluate to a 
node-set."

Comment: @Job - the XPath query in my answer creates a node-set. What is the actual query you're using?